# RoboContext in LoaderTestCase

Tags: android, testing, roboguice

I have issue with Roboguice 2.0 and testing. All injections in my app works fine, but in my LoaderTestCases I got an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.app.ContextImpl@42678aa0 does not appear to be a RoboGuice context (instanceof RoboContext)
at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.getScopedObjectMap(ContextScope.java:147)
at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.enter(ContextScope.java:79)........
```

I trying to search way to fix it. Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you share the source code for LoaderTestCases?

Comment: public class LoadersTest extends LoaderTestCase{... where LoaderTestCase is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/LoaderTestCase.html

Comment: I haven't used it, but if you share the code of your class that gives you the error, then maybe I can be more helpful.

Comment: There are any special cases. I have loader extends from RoboAsyncTaskLoader. And I have simple test for my loader. I use method getLoaderResultSynchronously(loader) for get loader result in my test. When my custom loader try to inject members I've got exception.